# Galois Field multiplication for large prime p (>340 bit)

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, applications

Lets first consider an integer less than p. Say A and B are of size ~339 bits. Now we split this integers into powers of $Z=2^{32}$, say
$$A= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{10} a_{k}Z^{k}, B= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{10} b_{k}Z^{k}$$

and we do the same with $p\sim 340$ bit.
$$p= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{10} p_{k}Z^{k}$$

where $a_0, b_0$ and $p_0$.

## Aiming the product mod p

If we do multiplying $C=A\cdot B$ first and reduce by p then, we need to calculate:
$$C=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{22} a_{k}Z^{k}$$

first.

Reducing mod p would then mean,

```
1. Split C in $C_1 . C_0$, where $C_1= [c_{22}, ..., c_{11}]$ and $C_0=[c_{11},...,c_0]$.

2. Compute $C_1$ mod $p$

3. While C_0 != 0 do
    3a) leftshift by multiples of 4-bit C_1
    3b) fill C_1 with C_0
    3c) leftshift by multiples of 4-bit C_0
    3d) C_1 mod p
```

Where "**leftshifting**" means, that we fill the leading zeros with previous entries, such that this count is on the end.

"**Filling**" means, that we fill those zeros in the end of $C_1$, by entries of $C_0$.

**Multiplication** means, that we need to carry the overflow.

## Question

Doing this, leads to the right product mod p. But I'm interested in some other mathematical methods to do this. But I need a practical description, like a "how to", even if this is only a scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Montgomery Multiplication is an excellent algorithm designed to do modular multiplication of large numbers modulo a prime $p$ (large or small) extremely fast. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) can tell you far more about it than I can, and it looks like it has detailed descriptions of various algorithms and implementations.

Comment: Well, actually I didn't get the Montgomery. I would like to append this algorithm to an easy example, just to understand the workflow right. 

Lets say: p=0x11 (=17) and A=0x9, B=0x1537 => A*B=0xbeef.
Well, we would calculate $B \bmod p$ first, and do then the multiplication. So, we would have $B=0x8$, but this wouldn't fit the given example of my first post. So lets consider $C=0xbeef$. How would then Montgomery work?

Comment: I apologize if I interpreted your question wrong but I thought your question was for a mathematical method of multiplying two large integers together in a Galois field of finite cardinality $p$ for some large prime $p$. The Montgomery Multiplication method does exactly that (well - it multiplies in an extra factor that you have to remove, but there are ways to adjust the product so this doesn't matter, and it does it for any $N$ instead of just a prime). The wikipedia page lists the full algorithm, so you can trace through the algorithm with that example. (and you don't need to do it in hex).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't read the multi precision point closly at the bottom of that wiki. My algorithm above seems to be wrong. The "mod p" and "leftshifting" part don't produce the right result. Do you know some algorithm/mathematical description, that would fit?

Comment: now I'm sure, my algorithm does not work. The repeatedly leftshifting and reducing thing, is false. I consider $(C\cdot B^n + A) \bmod p$. The result should lead to $$C\cdot B^n \bmod p + A \bmod p$$ that means for a coding aspect, that I have to reduce $B^n$ in a precomputation, which is then only a mapping. I just did handwritten tests without any calculator. After I decided to do something similar, but with Sagemath support, it turned out, that my reduction algorithm is mathematically wrong.